# How can I find out if an object implements a particular method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, methods

I am iterating through an NSArray that contains many different types of objects. There are many methods to figure out what class the object is. However, I haven't been able to find a good way to find out if an object can implement a particular function. I can put it in a try-catch but it will still output an error message in the console even if I'm catching the error. Is there a better way to do this?

Simple example:

```
@try {
    if ([element lowercaseString]) {
        //do something
    }
}
@catch (id theException) {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Check for respondsToSelector as many have answered. In Objective-C it isn't good style (in my and many others' opinion) to use exceptions to control program flow except for errors in programming. As you are checking if a method exists in this case, it isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As suggested, you can use [`respondsToSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418583-respondstoselector) message declared on `NSObject`.  The provided code would be like

```
if ([element respondsToSelector:@selector(lowercaseString)]) {
    // ... do work
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that the colons are an inseparable part of the selector. @selector(catFish) is completely different from @selector(catFish:).

Comment: hey is there a way to do something similar for properties? if i have a generic id item that i pulled from an array, i want to know if it has a certain property...

Answer (score 5):

Look at NSObject's respondsToSelector method

Answer (score 1):

A nice generic category to have in your code is this:

```
@interface NSObject (KMExtensions)

- (id)performSelectorIfResponds:(SEL)aSelector;
- (id)performSelectorIfResponds:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject;

@end

@implementation NSObject (KMExtensions)

- (id)performSelectorIfResponds:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if ( [self respondsToSelector:aSelector] ) {
        return [self performSelector:aSelector];
    }
    return NULL;
}

- (id)performSelectorIfResponds:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anObject
{
    if ( [self respondsToSelector:aSelector] ) {
        return [self performSelector:aSelector withObject:anObject];
    }
    return NULL;
}

@end
```

And then you can use:

```
[element performSelectorIfResponds:@selector(lowercaseString)];
```